# AutoMapper using operation to populate destination

Tags: automapper

I need to map a list from destination object to source, using a public method on the source object.

e.g.

```
public class Destination
{
    private IList<int> List = new List<int>();
    public void Add(int i) { List.Add(i); }
}

public class Source
{
    public int[] List { get; set; }
}
```

So in pseudo-pseudo language the mapping should be: 
Mapper.CreateMap foreach item in Source.List, invoke Source.Add(item)

Can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  Use the ConvertUsing syntax:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    .ConvertUsing(s =>
                    {
                        var d = new Destination();
                        foreach(var i in s.List)
                        {
                            d.Add(i);
                        }
                        return d;
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.

AutoMapper custom type converters accept only source and they return destination.

But, why don't you just implement an implicit type conversion from int[] to Destination?
http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/10/type-conversion-and-conversion-operators-in-c/

Comment: It's not because of type convertion, but rather due logic which needs to be performed when assigning (two way bindings in nhibernate) in the Add method

Comment: Yes, your implementation of implicit convertion operator will do foreach(var item in source) this.List.Add(item);

Comment: This does not work, because AutoMapper recognizes that it is array, and tries to do index mapping with no attempt to do a direct conversion between the array and collection, event when it is implemented. It actually fails on converting the IList key into integer.